# yeoman generator run tests automatically

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I have set up a backbone project using the Yeoman generator.

In the Gruntfile there is a task called server which runs a bunch of stuff but also livereload. There is another task called test that runs pretty much the same bunch of stuff but runs the tests once and no livereload.

I am a bit confused as to workflow. I cant run the server in one terminal window and the tests in another due to them using the same port.

It looks like you have to keep stopping the server to run the test each time.

How do I set it up so that the tests are run automatically each time the files change and the app gets reloaded?

Here is the gruntfile (default from generator):

```
'use strict';
var lrSnippet = require('grunt-contrib-livereload/lib/utils').livereloadSnippet;
var mountFolder = function (connect, dir) {
    return connect.static(require('path').resolve(dir));
};

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'
// templateFramework: 'handlebars'

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    // load all grunt tasks
    require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

    // configurable paths
    var yeomanConfig = {
        app: 'app',
        dist: 'dist'
    };

    grunt.initConfig({
        yeoman: yeomanConfig,
        watch: {
            coffee: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.coffee'],
                tasks: ['coffee:dist']
            },
            coffeeTest: {
                files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.coffee'],
                tasks: ['coffee:test']
            },
            compass: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['compass']
            },
            express: {
                files:[
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/*.html',
                    '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp}'
                ],
                tasks:  [ 'express:dev', 'livereload' ]
            },
            livereload: {
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/*.html',
                    '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp}'
                ],
                tasks: ['livereload']
            },
            handlebars: {
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/templates/*.hbs'
                ],
                tasks: ['handlebars']
            }
        },
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                // change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
                hostname: 'localhost'
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            lrSnippet,
                            mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                            mountFolder(connect, 'app')
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            test: {
                options: {
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                            mountFolder(connect, 'test')
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            mountFolder(connect, 'dist')
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        express: {
            options: {
                // Override defaults here
                port: '<%= connect.options.port %>'
            },
            dev: {
                options: {
                    script: 'server/app.js'
                }
            },
            prod: {
                options: {
                    script: 'server/app.js'
                }
            },
            test: {
                options: {
                    script: 'server/app.js'
                }
            }
        },
        open: {
            server: {
                path: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>'
            }
        },
        clean: {
            dist: ['.tmp', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*'],
            server: '.tmp'
        },
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
            },
            all: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '!<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
                'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
            ]
        },
        mocha: {
            all: {
                options: {
                    run: true,
                    urls: ['http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>/index.html']
                }
            }
        },
        coffee: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    // rather than compiling multiple files here you should
                    // require them into your main .coffee file
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
                    src: '*.coffee',
                    dest: '.tmp/scripts',
                    ext: '.js'
                }]
            },
            test: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/spec',
                    src: '*.coffee',
                    dest: 'test/spec'
                }]
            }
        },
        compass: {
            options: {
                sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
                cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
                imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
                fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
                importPath: 'app/bower_components',
                relativeAssets: true
            },
            dist: {},
            server: {
                options: {
                    debugInfo: true
                }
            }
        },
        requirejs: {
            dist: {
                // Options: https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js
                options: {
                    // `name` and `out` is set by grunt-usemin
                    baseUrl: 'app/scripts',
                    optimize: 'none',
                    paths: {
                        'templates': '../../.tmp/scripts/templates'
                    },
                    // TODO: Figure out how to make sourcemaps work with grunt-usemin
                    // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/30
                    //generateSourceMaps: true,
                    // required to support SourceMaps
                    // http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#sourcemapcomments
                    preserveLicenseComments: false,
                    useStrict: true,
                    wrap: true,
                    //uglify2: {} // https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2
                }
            }
        },
        useminPrepare: {
            html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
            options: {
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }
        },
        usemin: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
            css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
            options: {
                dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
            }
        },
        imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },
        cssmin: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
                        '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        htmlmin: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    /*removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                    // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/44
                    //collapseWhitespace: true,
                    collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                    removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                    useShortDoctype: true,
                    removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                    removeOptionalTags: true*/
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                    src: '*.html',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                }]
            }
        },
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        '*.{ico,txt}',
                        '.htaccess',
                        'images/{,*/}*.{webp,gif}'
                    ]
                }]
            }
        },
        bower: {
            all: {
                rjsConfig: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/main.js'
            }
        },
        handlebars: {
            compile: {
                options: {
                    namespace: 'JST',
                    amd: true
                },
                files: {
                    '.tmp/scripts/templates.js': ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/templates/*.hbs']
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.renameTask('regarde', 'watch');

    grunt.registerTask('createDefaultTemplate', function () {
        grunt.file.write('.tmp/scripts/templates.js', 'this.JST = this.JST || {};');
    });

    grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'open', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'coffee:dist',
            'createDefaultTemplate',
            'handlebars',
            'compass:server',
            'livereload-start',
            'connect:livereload',
            'open',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('expressserver', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'open', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'coffee:dist',
            'createDefaultTemplate',
            'handlebars',
            'compass:server',
            'express:dev',
            'livereload-start',
            'open',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('test', [
        'clean:server',
        'coffee',
        'createDefaultTemplate',
        'handlebars',
        'compass',
        'connect:test',
        'mocha'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'coffee',
        'createDefaultTemplate',
        'handlebars',
        'compass:dist',
        'useminPrepare',
        'requirejs',
        'imagemin',
        'htmlmin',
        'concat',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify',
        'copy',
        'usemin'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'jshint',
        'test',
        'build'
    ]);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are using [backbone-generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone), we don't have that capability right now.
But surely one of the feature we will be adding to it in future.

Until then you can do some tweaks on Gruntfile and [like this](https://gist.github.com/revathskumar/5944679/revisions).
For those tweaks to work you need to **rename the index.html in test directory** to test.html

Now if you run `grunt server:test` it will open the **test.html in browser**.

Regarding the port issue to use server and test at the same time, Right now I am not sure about any solution. But will try to find one and update here.